# Periodic functions proof

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

I need some help here.

Let $f$ be a  $2\pi$-periodic function, and define for an arbitrary $k\in\mathbb N$ a function $g(x) = f(kx)$. Show that $g$ is also $2\pi$-periodic.

What I've done:
$$
g(x) = f(kx)
$$
$$
g(x+T) = f((k+T)), \text{where } T = 2\pi.
$$

---

But i'm kinda stuck from here. Could anybody help me?

Comment: what 's your problem here ?its so easy just substitute $T=2\pi$

Comment: It should be $g(x+T)=f(kx+kT)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x+2\pi)=f(k(x+2\pi))=f(kx+2k\pi)=f(kx)=g(x)$$

Comment: And that's it? is that proof enough?

Comment: I was too fast. Now it should be correct.